# Точное время сервера

Tags: javascript

Есть следующая задача — отображать на странице у пользователя точное серверное время. Пытался сделать так, чтобы при загрузке страницы php записывал в javascript текущее время, а потом через каждую секунду к этому времени прибавлялась одна секунда. Но проблема в том, что если такую страничку открыть с телефона, а потом на какое-то время свернуть браузер, то будет отображаться последнее время перед сворачиванием браузера т.к. `setInterval` не работает, если браузер свёрнут. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно выйти из этой ситуации?

В идеале должно быть что-то вроде такого, но должно браться не время клиента, а время сервера.

```
function startTime()
{
    var tm=new Date();
    var h=tm.getHours();
    var m=tm.getMinutes();
    var s=tm.getSeconds();
    m=checkTime(m);
    s=checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
    t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);
}
function checkTime(i)
{
    if (i<10)
    {
        i="0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Вам надо передать с сервера стартовое время, сразу при открытии страницы вычислить разницу между локальным и серверным временем и при отображении времени брать текущее локальное, вычитать эту разницу и выводить.

Comment: Позанудствую: точное подобным способом в любом случае не получится, потому что с момента отправки сервером ответа до его получения клиентом неизбежно происходят задержки (при плохом интернете и несколько десятков секунд может набраться)

Comment: По поводу вычисления разницы уже думал, но вдруг пользователю вздумается перевести у себя часы пока страничка открыта :) Конечно, это маловероятно, но я думал, что есть какое-то универсальное решение, которое вообще не смотрит на время у клиента.

Comment: можно наверное и точное, измерить пинг, ввести поправку итд. возможно понадобится сокет

Comment: Для точного TCP слишком наворочен и непредсказуем, тот же NTP работает поверх UDP, а не TCP

Comment: я думаю, уже в установленном tcp соединении можно очень близко к результатам на udp подойти.

Comment: Только на надёжных соединениях, для мобильных интернетов не прокатит

Answer (score 2):

часы по времени сервера

```js
function fn(f, a) {
  var c = {
    cls: ["hour", "sp", "min", "spl", "sec"],
    formatTime: function(b) {
      b = Math.floor(b / 1E3);
      var a = Math.floor(b / 60),
        d = Math.floor(a / 60);
      b %= 60;
      a %= 60;
      return [c.two(d % 24), ":", c.two(a), ":", c.two(b)]
    },
    two: function(b) {
      return (9 < b ? "" : "0") + b
    },
    timer: function(b) {
      var a = performance.now();
      requestAnimationFrame(function g(e) {
        e -= a;
        e = c.formatTime(b + e);
        c.cls.forEach(function(a, b) {
          a.innerHTML = e[b]
        });
        requestAnimationFrame(g)
      })
    },
    init: function() {
      a = a.split(":");
      a = 36E5 * a[0] + 6E4 * a[1] + 1E3 * a[2];
      c.cls = c.cls.map(function(a) {
        var d = document.createElement("span");
        d.classList.add(a);
        f.appendChild(d);
        return d
      });
      c.timer(a)
    }
  };
  c.init()
};


var span = document.querySelector('.time');
fn(span, '23:59:55'); // fn(span, '%uptime%');
```

```css
 .time {
   color: rgb(102, 255, 255);
   background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
   padding: 2px 4px;
   border-radius: 4px;
 }
 .time span {
   margin: 2px;
   font-weight: bold;
 }
 .time .sp,
 .time .spl {
   color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   font-size: 20px;
 }
 .sec {
   color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
 }
```

```html
<span class="time"></span>
```